# push variables into object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push my variables into this object but not sure how todo this the proper way:

The jsonArray if manually inputted looks like so:

```
jsonArray = {
        "Person 1": ["Address Rd. City", "777 Street Ave. City"],
        "Person 2": ["Address2 Rd. City2", "777 Street Ave. City"]
        }
```

I have a loop in which I want to push variables into the jsonArray and i'm trying like so:

```
   var jsonArray = {};    
   for (var i = 0....my loop, etc)...
   jsonArray.push({fullname: [address, destination]});
```

This doesn't work, jsonArray always shows as {} when i JSON.stringify(jsonArray)

Comment: `jsonArray` is neither JSON, nor an Array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`jsonArray` — despite the misleading name — is actually an object so try instead

```
 for (...) {
    jsonArray[fullname] = [address, destination]; 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`push` is a method of `Array.prototype`. So change the first line to

```
var jsonArray = []; // array literal
```

Also declare it like

```
jsonArray = [
   ["Address Rd. City", "777 Street Ave. City"],
   ["Address2 Rd. City2", "777 Street Ave. City"]
]; // you can use indexes to get the elements
```

Comment: this is technically correct but you lose the reference between a person and his address and the capability to use the person as an index